# I don't understand R's predict

Tags: r, models, predict

I created a pair of models from my dataset (800 rows, 2 colums):

```
#1
m1=lm(A~A1, fish)
#2
mmars1=polymars(fish$A, fish)
#3
bestm1=loess.smooth(fish$A1, fish$A, span=best)
#4
bestm2=smooth.spline(fish$A1,fish$A, spar=best)
```

and then i tried to predict an y using a new x:

```
#Predict
#1
predict(m1, data.frame(xl=c(100000)))
#2
predict(mmars1, data.frame(xm=c(100000)))
#3
predict(bestm1, data.frame(xb1=c(100000)))
#4
predict(bestm2, data.frame(xb2=c(100000)))
```

#4 works fine, but i have problems with the other 3.
 #1 and #2 return 800 values instead of 1. 
 #3 gives me this error.

> Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict'
>   applied to an object of class "list"

What am i doing wrong with #1 and #2? Is there an alternative way to use the `predict()` method with `loess.smooth`?

Comment: We will need data. Please make your problem reproducible with expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `predict` your variables must have the same name they had when calling `lm`. In #1, you use `lm` with variable name `A1` but then use `predict` with variable name `xl`. The `predict` function doesn't understand your new data. Imagine what would happen with several independent variables...you need to stick to their names.

Use `predict(m1, list(A1=100000))` instead.

As to #2, I've never used package `polspline` before, but it seems that your call to `polymars` is wrong. The second argument must be the predictors, and as of now you include the response as a predictor because you give the full data.frame. So you should do:

```
mmars1 <- polymars(fish$A, fish$A1)
predict(mmars1, fish$A1)
```

Same for #3. It seems that `loess.smooth` already gives you the fitted points. You can use the `evaluation` parameter to tell how many points along your predictor you want to fit:

```
bestm1 <- loess.smooth(fish$A1, fish$A, evaluation=50)
```

will give you a list of 50 points along `A1` with the fitted points in `A`. Alternatively, you can use `loess` instead of `loess.smooth`:

```
bestm1 <- loess(A~A1, fish)
predict(bestm1, data.frame(A1=100000))
```